# Set Cron trigger for once

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, crontrigger

How can I set Quartz cron trigger for run at one specifc date and time for once?

Eg: run something at 12.30pm on 2017-06-30 and never run again

Comment: why not use another type of trigger then?

Comment: which trigger u meant?

Comment: see their docs http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/overview/features.html

Comment: or http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-05.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to achieve using CronTrigger try like below

```
<bean id="newTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="oneTimeJob"/>
        <property name="cronExpression" value="0 30 12 30 6 ? 2017"/>

    </bean>
```

Or As @scary wombat mention Use SimpleTrigger

```
SimpleTrigger trigger = (SimpleTrigger) newTrigger() 
    .withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
    .startAt(myStartTime) // some Date date 30.06.2017 12:30
    .forJob("job1", "group1") // identify job with name, group strings
    .build();
```

Comment: I would suggest the second option